# How can I sequentially read and then evaluate from a test set and output the predictions to a file in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I noticed that CIFAR10 in TensorFlow does batch evaluation. The batches are created with many threads. As a result of this, the image sequences are pseudo random in the batch.

To circumvent this, my current implementation of doing evaluation is to

1. Set num_epochs in tf.train.string_input_producer to 1, thus reading the TFRecords file only once.
2. Set num_threads in tf.train.batch to 1, thus only using a single thread and preventing multiple reads from the same TFRecords file.

Following that, I print the predicted results on the console.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is this the best way to evaluate a test set sequentially?
2. Is simply opening a file and writing the predicted results out the best way to do this?

Thank you for your help.